# How to find 3 numbers in increasing order and increasing indices in an array in linear time

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, time-complexity

I came across this question on a website. As mentioned there, it was asked in amazon interview. I couldn't figure out a proper solution in given constraint.

Given an array of `n` integers, find *3 elements* such that `a[i] < a[j] < a[k]` and `i < j < k` in **O(n)** time.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @HenkHolterman My thinking took me to similar direction as of twall's approach below. But finally I ended up with finding out bugs in my own solution... :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So here is how you can solve the problem. You need to iterate over the array three times. On the first iteration mark all the values that have an element greater than them on the right and on the second iteration mark all the elements smaller than them on their left. Now your answer would be with an element that has both:

```
int greater_on_right[SIZE];
int smaller_on_left[SIZE];
memset(greater_on_rigth, -1, sizeof(greater_on_right));
memset(smaller_on_left, -1, sizeof(greater_on_right));

int n; // number of elements;
int a[n]; // actual elements;
int greatest_value_so_far = a[n- 1];
int greatest_index = n- 1;
for (int i = n -2; i >= 0; --i) {
   if (greatest_value_so_far > a[i]) {
     greater_on_right[i] = greatest_index;
   } else {
     greatest_value_so_far = a[i];
     greatest_index = i;
   }
}

// Do the same on the left with smaller values


for (int i =0;i<n;++i) {
  if (greater_on_right[i] != -1 && smaller_on_left[i] != -1) {
    cout << "Indices:" << smaller_on_left[i] << ", " << i << ", " << greater_on_right[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

This solution iterates 3 times over the whole array and is therefore linear. I have not provided the whole solution so that you can train yourself on the left to see if you get my idea. I am sorry not to give just some tips but I couldn't figure out how to give a tip without showing the actual solution.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Great thinking! My way of doing it had to many flaws, I admit, I should have thought in a broader sense: linear doesn't at all mean in one iteration, even though I am quite sure it would be doable. I'll try to find a solution later!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if the input is {1,2,3,4} you are not finding all the triplets, which are [1,2,3][1,2,4][1,3,4][2,3,4]

Comment: @daniele you are only required to find **one** triplet, not all of them. You can not expect to be able to print all triplets in linear time as their number may be cubic.

Comment: @devsnd: I found (not thought of myself) a one-pass solution that only uses O(1) state (4 variables).  I posted it as an answer, with links to the original author on a programming-challenge site.  I had been thinking you'd need to keep track of many potential candidates for back-tracking, but it turns out you don't have to.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The logic has a local maxima handling problem. In case of an array 8,9,7,10,2,3,11 -> greater_on_right only points to the last element which is not true. With this input, it should ideally print the output as 8,9,10 and not 8,9,11. The following is the output from your snippet:                                                                   Indices:0, 1, 6
List:8, 9, 11
Indices:2, 3, 6
List:7, 10, 11
Indices:4, 5, 6
List:2, 3, 11

Comment: @Vivek what do you mean by ` it should ideally print the output as`. I don't see any constraint on the triplet I find

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I meant that though in that list, 8,9,10 is the first triplet, this code can't print it.

Comment: @Vivek please read the question again. OP asks for algorithm to find ONE triplet not all of them.  By the way my code can be all adapted to find the leftmost one quite easily

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev OK I was expecting that even if not all triplets are found, it would be the first triplet that would be found.And yes, it can probably be easily adapted to find the leftmost one.

Answer (score 3):

One-pass linear time, with O(1) extra space (4 variables).  Very efficient (only a couple comparisons/branches per iteration, and not much data shuffling).

**This is *NOT* my original idea or algorithm**, I just tidied up and commented [the code in an ideone fork](http://ideone.com/UZz45E).  You can add new test-cases to the code there and run it online.  The [original](http://ideone.com/QefD9V) is by [Kenneth, posted in comments on a thread on www.geeksforgeeks.org](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-sorted-subsequence-of-size-3-in-linear-time/#comment-1573367479).  Great algorithm, but the original implementation had some really silly code outside of the actual loop.  (e.g., instead of local variables, lets use two member-variables in a class, and implement the function as a member-function of `class Solution`...  And the variable-names sucked.  I went for quite verbose ones.)

Kenneth, if you want to post your code as an answer, go ahead.  I'm not trying to steal credit for the algo.  (I did put some work into writing up this explanation, and thinking through *why* it works, though.)

The main article above the discussion thread has the same solution as Ivaylo Strandjev's answer.  (The main-article's code is what Pramod posted as an answer to this question, months after Ivalyo's answer.  That's how I found the interesting answers in comments there.)

---

Since you only need to find *a* solution, not all of them, there aren't as many corner cases as you'd expect.  It turns out you don't need to keep track of every possible start and middle value you've seen, or even backtrack at all, if you choose the right things to keep as state.

---

The main tricks are:

- The last value in a sequence of monotonically decreasing values is the only one you need to consider.  This applies to both first(low) and second(mid) candidate elements.
- Any time you see a smaller candidate for a **middle** element, you can start fresh from there, just looking for either a final element or an even better mid-candidate.

  If you didn't already find a sequence of 3 increasing elements before an element smaller than your current mid-candidate, min-so-far and the new smaller middle-candidate are as good (as forgiving, as flexible) as you can do out of the numbers you've already checked.  (See the comments in the code for a maybe-better way of phrasing this.)

  Several other answers make the mistake of starting fresh every time they see a new smallest or largest element, rather than middle.  You track the current min that you've seen, but you don't react or make use of it until you see a new middle.

To find new candidate middle elements, you check if they're smaller than the current middle-candidate, and != min element seen so far.

I'm not sure if this idea can be extended to 4 or more values in sequence.  Finding a new candidate 3rd value might require tracking the min between the current candidate second and third separately from the overall min.  This could get tricky, and require a lot more conditionals.  But if it can be done correctly with constant-size state and one pass without backtracking, it would still be linear time.

```c++
// Original had this great algorithm, but a clumsy and weird implementation (esp. the code outside the loop itself)

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Find a sorted subsequence of size 3 in one pass, linear time
//returns an empty list on not-found
vector<int> find3IncreasingNumbers(int * arr, int n)
{
    int min_so_far = arr[0];
    int c_low, c_mid;            // candidates
    bool have_candidates = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)  {
        if(arr[i] <= min_so_far)  // less-or-equal prevents values == min from ending up as mid candidates, without a separate else if()continue;
            min_so_far = arr[i];
        else if(!have_candidates || arr[i] <= c_mid) {
            // If any sequence exists with a middle-numbers we've already seen (and that we haven't already finished)
            // then one exists involving these candidates
            c_low = min_so_far;
            c_mid = arr[i];
            have_candidates = true;
        } else {
            // have candidates and arr[i] > c_mid
            return vector<int> ( { c_low, c_mid, arr[i] } );
        }
    }

    return vector<int>();  // not-found
}

int main()
{
    int array_num = 1;

// The code in this macro was in the original I forked.  I just put it in a macro.  Starting from scratch, I might make it a function.
#define TRYFIND(...) do { \
        int arr[] = __VA_ARGS__ ; \
        vector<int> resultTriple = find3IncreasingNumbers(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])); \
        if(resultTriple.size()) \
            cout<<"Result of arr" << array_num << ": " <<resultTriple[0]<<" "<<resultTriple[1]<<" "<<resultTriple[2]<<endl; \
        else \
            cout << "Did not find increasing triple in arr" << array_num << "." <<endl; \
        array_num++; \
    }while(0)

    TRYFIND( {12, 11, 10, 5, 6, 2, 30} );
    TRYFIND( {1, 2, 3, 4} );
    TRYFIND( {4, 3, 1, 2} );
    TRYFIND( {12, 1, 11, 10, 5, 4, 3} );
    TRYFIND( {12, 1, 11, 10, 5, 4, 7} );
    TRYFIND( {12, 11, 10, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3} );
    TRYFIND( {12, 11, 10, 5, 2, 4, 1, 6} );
    TRYFIND( {5,13,6,10,3,7,2} );
    TRYFIND( {1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 5} );
    TRYFIND( {1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5} );
    TRYFIND( {2, 3, 1, 4} );
    TRYFIND( {3, 1, 2, 4} );
    TRYFIND( {2, 4} );

    return 0;
}
```

Making a CPP macro which can take an initializer-list as a parameter is ugly:
[Is it possible to pass a brace-enclosed initializer as a macro parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913103/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-as-a-macro-parameter)

It was very much worth it to be able to add new test-cases easily, though, without editing `arr4` to `arr5` in 4 places.

Answer (score 1):

I posted another approach to resolve it [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19879).

```
#include<stdio.h>

// A function to fund a sorted subsequence of size 3
void find3Numbers(int arr[], int n)
{
   int max = n-1; //Index of maximum element from right side
   int min = 0; //Index of minimum element from left side
   int i;

   // Create an array that will store index of a smaller
   // element on left side. If there is no smaller element
   // on left side, then smaller[i] will be -1.
   int *smaller = new int[n];
   smaller[0] = -1;  // first entry will always be -1
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (arr[i] < arr[min])
       {
          min = i;
          smaller[i] = -1;
       }
       else
          smaller[i] = min;
   }

   // Create another array that will store index of a
   // greater element on right side. If there is no greater
   // element on right side, then greater[i] will be -1.
   int *greater = new int[n];
   greater[n-1] = -1;  // last entry will always be -1
   for (i = n-2; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       if (arr[i] > arr[max])
       {
          max = i;
          greater[i] = -1;
       }
       else
          greater[i] = max;
   }

   // Now find a number which has both a greater number on
   // right side and smaller number on left side
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if (smaller[i] != -1 && greater[i] != -1)
       {
          printf("%d %d %d", arr[smaller[i]],
                 arr[i], arr[greater[i]]);
          return;
       }
   }

   // If we reach number, then there are no such 3 numbers
   printf("No such triplet found");
   return;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {12, 11, 10, 5, 6, 2, 30};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    find3Numbers(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: exactly same as the solution given by @Ivaylo Strandjev.

Comment: That link is to a programming-challenge site where many solutions are posted in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:
In JAVA:

```
List<Integer> OrderedNumbers(int[] nums){
    List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
    int n = nums.length;
    //if less then 3 elements, return the empty list
    if(n<3) return res;

    //run 1 forloop to determine local min and local max for each index
    int[] lMin = new int[n], lMax = new int[n];
    lMin[0] = nums[0]; lMax[n-1] = nums[n-1];
    for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++){
        lMin[i] = Math.min(lMin[i-1], nums[i]);
        lMax[n-i-1] = Math.max(lMax[n-i],nums[n-i-1]);
    }

    //if a condition is met where min(which always comes before nums[i] and max) < nums[i] < max, add to result set and return;
    for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++){
        if(lMin[i]<nums[i] && nums[i]<lMax[i]){
            res.add(lMin[i]);
            res.add(nums[i]);
            res.add(lMax[i]);
            return res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very similar to computing the longest increasing subsequence, with the constraint that size of this subsequence must necessarily be equal to three. The LIS problem (with O(nlog(n)) solution) can easily be modified for this specific problem. This solution has **O(n)** single pass complexity with **O(1)** space.

This solution requires that only unique elements occur in the list. We use an [online solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm). As we encounter any new element, it has potential to extend the present most optimum subsequence or start a new subsequence. In this case, as the maximum length of increasing subsequence is three, any new element currently being processed can either extend a sequence of size 2 to 3 and 1 to 2. So we maintain active lists containing the most optimum elements.

In this particular problem, the maximum number of active lists we have to maintain are 2 - one of size 2 and another of size 1. As soon as we hit a list with size 3, we have our answer. We make sure each active list terminates with minimum number. For more detailed explanation of this idea, refer [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/).

At any point of time in the online solution, these two active lists will store the most efficient values of the list - the end of the list will be smallest element that can be placed there. Suppose the two lists are:

Size 2 list => [a,b]

Size 1 list => [c]

The initial list can be easily written (refer to the code below). Suppose the next number to be entered is `d`. Then cases (cascading in execution) are as follows:

Case 1: `d > b`. 
We have our answer in this case, as `a < b < d`.

Case 2: `b > d > a`. In this the list of size 2 can be optimally represented by having end as `d` instead of `b`, as every element occurring after `d` greater than `b` will also be greater than `d`. So we replace b by d.

Case 3: `d < c`. As Case 1 and 2 fails, it automatically implies that `d < a`. In such a case, it may start a new list with size one. The list with size one is compared to get the most efficient active list. If this case is true, we replace `c` by `d`.

Case 4: `Otherwise`. This case implies that `d < b` and `c < d`. In such a case, the list of size 2 is inefficient. So we replace `[a, b]` by `[c, d]`.

```C++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    int two_size_first;
    int two_size_mid;
    int one_size;
    int end_index;
    vector<int> arr;

    Solution(int size) {
        end_index = two_size_mid = two_size_first = one_size = -1;
        int temp;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            cin >> temp;
            arr.push_back(temp);
        }   
    }

    void solve() {
        if (arr.size() < 3)
            return;

        one_size = two_size_first = arr[0];
        two_size_mid = INT_MAX;

        for(int i=1; i<arr.size(); i++) {
            if(arr[i] > two_size_mid) {
                end_index = i;
                return;
            }
            else if (two_size_first < arr[i] && arr[i] < two_size_mid) {
                two_size_mid = arr[i];
            }
            else if (one_size > arr[i]) {
                one_size = arr[i];
            }
            else {
                two_size_first = one_size;
                two_size_mid = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    void result() {
        if (end_index != -1) {
            cout << two_size_first << " " << two_size_mid << " " << arr[end_index] << endl; 
        }
        else {
            cout << "No such sequence found" << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter "  << size << " array elements" << endl;
    Solution solution(size);

    solution.solve();
    solution.result();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This idea can be used to find increasing subsequences of size greater than 3 too.

Answer (score 0):

My Approach  - **O(N) time two passes O(1) space with two variables used**

for each element of the array we visit we maintain the minimum possible to its left to check for whether this element may be the middle element and also keep record of minimum middle element to its left to check for whether this element may be a candidate third element or it may form a middle element with lower value than found so far.Initailise min so far and middle so far to INT_MAX,

Fr each element thus we have to check :

If a particular array element is greater than the minimum of middle element so far than this array element is the answer with thi as the  third element and the min middle element as the mid element(We will have to search for the third element afterward by one pass)

Else If a particular array element is greater than the minimum so far than this element could be a candidate middle element and now we have to check if the candidate middle element is less than the current middle element if so update the current middle element

ELSE If a particular array element is less than the minimum so far then update the minimum so far with arr[i] .

So this way for each element of the array we visit we maintain the minimum possible to its left to check for whether this element may be the middle element and also keep record of minimum middle element to its left to check for whether this element may be a candidate third element or it may form a middle element with lower value than found so far.
    #include
    using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
int i,j,k,n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
for(i = 0;i < n;++i)
    cin >> arr[i];
int m = INT_MAX,sm = INT_MAX,smi;// m => minimum so far found to left
for(i = 0;i < n;++i)// sm => smallest middle element found so far to left
{
    if(arr[i]>sm){break;}// This is the answer
    else if(arr[i] < m ){m = arr[i];}
    else if(arr[i] > m){if(arr[i]<sm){sm = arr[i];smi = i;}}
    else {;}
}
if((i < n)&&(arr[i]>sm))
{
    for(j = 0;j < smi;++j){if(arr[j] < sm){cout << arr[j] << " ";break;}}
    cout << sm << " " << arr[i]<< endl;
}
else 
    cout << "Such Pairs Do Not Exist" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my O(n) solution with O(1) space complexity:-
Just a function which returns a vector consisiting of three values(if exixts)

```
`vector<int> find3Numbers(vector<int> A, int N)
 {
    int first=INT_MAX,second=INT_MAX,third=INT_MAX,i,temp=-1;
    vector<int> ans;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(first!=INT_MAX&&second!=INT_MAX&&third!=INT_MAX)
        {
            ans.push_back(first);
            ans.push_back(second);
            ans.push_back(third);
            return ans;
        }
        if(A[i]<=first)
        {
            if(second!=INT_MAX)
            {
                if(temp==-1)
                {
                    temp=first;
                }
                first=A[i];
            }
            else
            {
                first=A[i];
            }
        }
        else if(A[i]<=second)
        {
            second=A[i];
            temp=-1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(temp!=-1)
            {
                first=temp;
            }
            third=A[i];
        }
    }
    if(first!=INT_MAX&&second!=INT_MAX&&third!=INT_MAX)
    {
        ans.push_back(first);
        ans.push_back(second);
        ans.push_back(third);
        return ans;
    }
    return ans;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is O(n) time and O(1) space complexity solution for this problem

```cpp
bool increasingTriplet(vector<int>& a) {

    int i,n=a.size(),first=INT_MAX,second=INT_MAX;
    if(n<3)
        return false;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=first)
            first = a[i];
        else if(a[i]<=second)
            second = a[i];
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function returns true if there exists a pair of 3 elements which are in sorted increasing order in array.
You can also modify this function to print all 3 elements or their indexes. Just update their indexes as well along with variable first and second.

Answer (score 0):

My solution below.

```
public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {

    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i]<min1) {
            min1 = nums[i];
        } else if (nums[i]<min2 && nums[i]>min1) {
            min2=nums[i];
        } else if (nums[i]>min2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, i couldn't resist but to solve the puzzle...
Here is my solution.

```
//array indices
int i, j, k = -1;
//values at those indices
int iv, jv, kv = 0;
for(int l=0; l<a.length(); l++){
    //if there is a value greater than the biggest value
    //shift all values from k to i
    if(a[l]>kv || j == -1 || i == -1){
        i = j;
        iv = jv;
        j = k;
        jv = kv
        kv = a[l]
        k = l
    }
    if(iv < jv && jv < kv && i < j && j < k){
        break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: +1.  Nice.  :)  
I wouldn't have used iv, jv, and kv though, but I guess it's more efficient that way so I can't complain.  How would you know you've found it?  Check if `i != j && j != k`.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? For the input "100, 1,2,3" you will only set kv = 100  and that is it, while there is a valid set of three numbers.

Comment: I updated my answer, thanks for the input, izomorphius & Neil

Comment: OK and now what would you do for the input "1001,100,200,1,2,3"? I do not think your approach is in the correct direction.

Comment: It fails when a new higher-than-kv value isn't part of the sequence.  It fails on `1 5 2 3` (because the shift drops the 1 instead of the 5).  I think even fixing this bug will still leave an algo that can miss things, because it can't backtrack to consider sequences that start with a value it ignored as less than the `kv` it had while looking for a 3rd increasing value after two other candidates.  (So this idea is **fundamentally flawed**, unfortunately.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to create two variables:

```
1. index_sequence_length_1 = index i such
   a[i] is minimal number
2. index_sequence_length_2 = index j such
   There is index i < j such that a[i] < a[j] and a[j] is minimal
```

Iterate over whole array and update this variables in each iteration.

If you iterate over element that is greater than a[index_sequence_length_2], than you found your sequence.

Comment: I think the description is incomplete! Lots of cases have not been considered and the approach is not leading to to a correct solution.

Comment: Yup, this considers the overall minimum element as the only candidate for the start of the sequence.  Fails on `2 3 1 4`.  After the first pass, `i` points to 1, `j` points to `4`.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate once and done:

```
public static int[] orderedHash(int[] A){
    int low=0, mid=1, high=2;
    for(int i=3; i<A.length; i++){
        if(A[high]>A[mid] && A[mid]>A[low])
            break;

        if(A[low]>A[i])
            low=mid=high=i;
        else if(low == mid && mid == high)
            mid = high = i;
        else if(mid == high){
            if(A[high]<A[i])
                high = i;
            else
                mid = high = i;
        }
        else if(A[mid]<A[i])
            high = i;
        else if( A[high]<A[i]){
            mid = high;
            high =i;
        }
        else
            mid=high=i;
    }
    return new int[]{A[low],A[mid],A[high]};
}//
```

Then test with main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] D = {{1, 5, 5, 3, 2, 10},
        {1, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10},
        {1, 10, 5, 3, 2, 6, 12},
        {1, 10, 5, 6, 8, 12, 1},
        {1, 10, 5, 12, 1, 2, 3, 40},
        {10, 10, 10, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9}};
    for (int[] E : D) {
        System.out.format("%s GIVES %s%n", Arrays.toString(E), Arrays.toString(orderedHash(E)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its always good to write algorithm for better understanding of others rather than just bombarding your code.
Even if you are doing so, it should be well commented. :)
Codes are welcome  in case the idea can not be expressed well in algorithms...

Comment: This is just a for loop and a few if-else so I figured this was easy to follow. Any specifics you don't understand? I will be happy to help.

Comment: Now I looked at your code and I'm afraid its not producing correct result!
Try this test case: 3,10,5,1,11

Comment: Good comments would say something about what invariants are maintained, and how the algorithm approaches the task.  Reading that instead of mentally tracing through the code would be *much* faster.

Comment: This algo gets distracted by new minimum elements (since it restarts with `low=mid=high=i` every time it finds an element smaller than `A[low]`).  I'm pretty sure it fails on `3 4 1 5`, for that reason.  It's only safe to ignore the first sequence of monotonically decreasing elements.

Answer (score -1):

What if you build a max-heap O(n) and then do Extract-Max O(1) 3 times?

Comment: It doesn't fulfil the constraints mentioned!! Moreover you need to check the complexities you mentioned... :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with only one iteration.

I am using stack to compute for each index k whether there exists two other indices i & j such that a[i] < a[j] < a[k].

```
bool f(vector<int> a) {

    int n = a.size();
    stack<int> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        while(!s.empty() and a[s.top()]>=a[i]){
            s.pop();
        }

        if (s.size()>=2) // s.size()>=k-1
        {
            return 1;
        }
        s.push(i);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

And important thing is that we can extend this problem to M such indices in the general case instead of k indices.

Comment: Hello anyone, Is there any limitation of this solution ?

Comment: @greybeard, it wiil return true as 2,3,4 are one such triplet. code corrected . if you check the stack size just before the push() we can miss out a possible triplet. for e.g  for 1,2,3 we will return 0 in that case.

Comment: @greybeard, yes, you are right. I misunderstood earlier, But this optimization would reduce the space complexity by O(1) only. 

Anyways, In general space complexity is O(k). For this problem, its constant space and one pass process( actually 2*n steps in worst case ).

Clearly this is better than previous in terms of no. of steps and exact space complexity.

Comment: (The question runs `find 3 elements` without spelling out in black and white what to do on success, let alone failure. Stacking the values would work just the same as having an array and stacking indices, making this a (_partially_ correct, depending on the machine model) constant space on-line algorithm.)

Comment: Yes , Stacking the values instead of indices is required here for making the algorithm online in case if user asks the particular indices. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: (bummer. Doesn't help I deleted my comment about confidence before …) What about 2, 3, 1, 4?

Comment: @greybeard: yup, looks like this whole idea can't work, because it discards everything upon seeing a new minimum.  A low value in the middle of a sequence throws it off.  It's only safe to ignore a sequence of monotonically decreasing elements (i.e. take the last one of such a sequence as the first or middle element).  This is the same problem as kasavbere's answer.

Comment: @greybeard, thanks, a very good observation indeed. yeah I am surprised as to why did it take us so long to figure out !

Comment: i am sure this solution does not work for the case [3, 4, 1], it yields EXISTS when it is not actually, can you elaborate on that.