# Why does a C macro invocation eat up curly braces?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Consider:

```
#define TEST(x) x
int arr[2] = TEST({1, 2});
```

I would expect it to be preprocessed into `int arr[2] = {1, 2};`

Instead, both gcc and clang complain. gcc 7.3.0:

```
./test.c:2:25: error: macro "TEST" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 int arr[2] = TEST({1, 2});
```

clang 3.8.1:

```
./test.c:2:23: error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
int arr[2] = TEST({1, 2});
```

I couldn't find any mention of curly braces being treated specially in the C language standard section on macros (6.10).

Why does this happen?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913103/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-as-a-macro-parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that the invocation is split by comma to find the arguments, ignoring any characters such as { and } (see below for quote from the standard). Only regular parens are treated specially.

So `TEST({1, 2})` is interpreted as being passed two arguments, `{1` and `2}`.
Indeed:

```
#define TEST(x, y) | x | y |
int arr[2] = TEST({1, 2});
```

Is preprocessed into:

```
int arr[2] = | {1 | 2} |;
```

Section 6.10.3.11:

> The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses
>   forms the list of arguments for the function-like macro. The individual arguments within
>   the list are separated by comma preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens
>   between matching inner parentheses do not separate arguments. If there are sequences of
>   preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise act as
>   preprocessing directives, 172) the behavior is undefined.