# File Encryption and Decryption using a given key

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I have a problem for school and I can't seem to figure it out. Basically, i'm in an intro to object oriented programming class, so I only need to complete this as basic as possible without using anything fancy that I haven't learned yet. Currently learning about dictionaries and sets, I need to use a dictionary that has a code written in it to encrypt a document that has a long string on one line.

So I need one part to read the dictionary and open the text file containing the string.

`"The course Introduction to Object Oriented Programming uses the Python programming language."`

I need to then use the code from this dictionary to encrypt it and write the encrypted version of the string to another text file called `encrypt.txt`.

```
CODE = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}
```

This is the code I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated and an explanation in layman's terms would also be greatly appreciated.

```
CODE = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}

def main():
    #Open the file you want to encrypt.
    infile = str(input('Enter the name of the input file: '))
    #read its contents
    dtext = open(infile, 'r')
    #read the line from the file
    dtext = dtext.readlines()

    #strip the newline
    #dtext = dtext.rstrip('\n')

    #call the encryptText function
    encryptText(dtext)

def encryptText(dtext):
    #enter the name of the file to write to
    outfile = str(input('Enter the name of the output file: '))
    #open the file to send encrypted text to
    etext = open(outfile, 'w')
    #set accumulator value
    count = 0
    #create a for loop to read each separate character
    for line in dtext:
        wordList = line.split()
        print(dtext, CODE[dtext])
    count += 1

main()
```

Comment: What went wrong? I got `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` ... is that what you see?

Comment: Yeah, but I think I figured out that part, but now i'm getting a new error... KeyError: ' '

Comment: In my soltion I used `dict.get(c,c)` which tries to get the mapped c but otherwise passes the original through. For ascii text, it not encode things like tabs and newlines.

Comment: Side-note: This is a *perfect* case for `str.translate`. Just preprocess `CODE = str.maketrans(CODE)` (to fix up the key definitions), then converting through your table is just `cipher = plain.translate(CODE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. That means you cannot edit them after creation, in direct contrast to arrays. You will have to build a new string in order to encrypt your text. You will also likely need to do this one character at a time. Since you have the text of the file in dtext as a string, you can loop through the chars in the original string like so:

```
for i in range (0, len(dtext)):
    # add new character to string
```

(I'm breaking this apart so you cannot just copy and paste)

You must create a new string to put the encrypted text in outside of that for loop.

```
enc = ""
```

In order to encrypt the value by making a substitution you can add character one at a time to the encrypted string in that for loop if they are in the dictionary you defined. Something to the effect of

```
if (dtext[i] in CODE.keys()):
    enc += CODE[dtext[i]]
```

Then write the new string to a file and you're good to go.

A dictionary in python is effectively an array that is indexable by a key. This key maps to a given value just like an array index maps to some value. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm for more details.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I understand that! I will try and see if I can get it now. I was using this and started to get somewhere, but your method makes more sense.                              for line in dtext:
                                              for ch in line:
                                                   print(ch, CODE[ch])

Answer (score 1):

You need to encrypt character by character and you need to take the result and build it back into a string. `str.join` turns a sequence of characters into a string and a generator can be written to encrypt each character... put them together and you have your solution.

```
CODE = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}

def main():
    #Open the file you want to encrypt.
    infile = str(input('Enter the name of the input file: '))
    #read its contents
    dtext = open(infile, 'r')
    #read the line from the file
    dtext = dtext.readlines()

    #strip the newline
    #dtext = dtext.rstrip('\n')

    #call the encryptText function
    encryptText(dtext)

def encryptText(dtext):
    #enter the name of the file to write to
    outfile = str(input('Enter the name of the output file: '))
    #open the file to send encrypted text to
    etext = open(outfile, 'w')
    #set accumulator value

    #create a for loop to read each separate character
    for line in dtext:
        # encrypt character by character then join to a string
        encrypted = ''.join(CODE.get(c, c) for c in line)
        print(repr(line), repr(encrypted))
        etext.write(encrypted)
    etext.close()

main()
```

Comment: For the record, given this appears to be Python 3, you could simplify dramatically. After defining `CODE`, add the line `CODE = str.maketrans(CODE)` to convert it to a `str.translate` friendly `dict`, then replace the genexpr and `join` with just `encrypted = line.translate(CODE)`. Should be *much* faster, and you're using the most straightforward tool for the job.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I agree there are better ways and ways this code could be cleaner but since this is for a newbie programming class, I wanted to disturb it as little as possible. If I was teaching a beginner class and got your solution I'd consider an F for cheating!

Comment: Really? I mean, if you look up `str` methods, `str.translate` is basically describing how you'd use a `dict` of exactly the form given (well, okay, it needs to be fixed up by `maketrans` to use the ordinals as keys, but close enough). It's actually more likely to be found by a newbie looking blindly than by a moderately experienced programmer who already knows "the right way to do it" but never encountered that specific method before.

Comment: I'm with tdelaney, I'm trying to to keep it as simple as possible because we haven't learned that much yet. As I do really appreciate learning more than i'm being taught, I need to learn it the easiest way possible at first for these labs! don't want to cheat haha

Comment: But your code worked tdelaney, except I don't think I have learned how to use join yet which is the only problem.

Comment: @DillonFornaro - shadowranger has a point. Python has a robust help system and part of learning is learning how to use it. `help(str)` is an interesting read.

Comment: If you were able to get it to work in a way you understand use that. Your take on playing safe for your class is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

*tdelaney's answer was correct, but I took it and made it a more simpler version. I changed it a bit. This is what I did:*

Instead of joining to an empty string, I just removed that part completely. I just iterated over the entire string character by character and then as tdelaney did, used the get method to use the key in the code dictionary.

```
CODE = {'A': ')', 'a': '0', 'B': '(', 'b': '9', 'C': '*', 'c': '8',
    'D': '&', 'd': '7', 'E': '^', 'e': '6', 'F': '%', 'f': '5',
    'G': '$', 'g': '4', 'H': '#', 'h': '3', 'I': '@', 'i': '2',
    'J': '!', 'j': '1', 'K': 'Z', 'k': 'z', 'L': 'Y', 'l': 'y',
    'M': 'X', 'm': 'x', 'N': 'W', 'n': 'w', 'O': 'V', 'o': 'v',
    'P': 'U', 'p': 'u', 'Q': 'T', 'q': 't', 'R': 'S', 'r': 's',
    'S': 'R', 's': 'r', 'T': 'Q', 't': 'q', 'U': 'P', 'u': 'p',
    'V': 'O', 'v': 'o', 'W': 'N', 'w': 'n', 'X': 'M', 'x': 'm',
    'Y': 'L', 'y': 'l', 'Z': 'K', 'z': 'k', '!': 'J', '1': 'j',
    '@': 'I', '2': 'i', '#': 'H', '3': 'h', '$': 'G', '4': 'g',
    '%': 'F', '5': 'f', '^': 'E', '6': 'e', '&': 'D', '7': 'd',
    '*': 'C', '8': 'c', '(': 'B', '9': 'b', ')': 'A', '0': 'a',
    ':': ',', ',': ':', '?': '.', '.': '?', '<': '>', '>': '<',
    "'": '"', '"': "'", '+': '-', '-': '+', '=': ';', ';': '=',
    '{': '[', '[': '{', '}': ']', ']': '}'}

def main():
    #Open the file you want to encrypt.
    infile = str(input('Enter the name of the input file: '))
    #read its contents
    dtext = open(infile, 'r')
    #read the line from the file
    dtext = dtext.readlines()

    #call the encryptText function
    encryptText(dtext)

def encryptText(dtext):
    #enter the name of the file to write to
    outfile = str(input('Enter the name of the output file: '))
    #open the file to send encrypted text to
    etext = open(outfile, 'w')
    #create a for loop to read each separate character
    for line in dtext:
        # encrypt character by character then join to a string
        for c in line:
            encrypted = (CODE.get(c, c))
            etext.write(encrypted)
    #close the file
    etext.close()

main()
```

Comment: Just so you know, it's not convention to answer your own question. The last time i did, i was heavily downvoted and lost quite a bit of rep. I'm not going to do anything about it, b/c i think it makes sense. I thought i'd warn you though.

Comment: Oh really? Sorry, I'm new to all of this and this website. I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: @thedevelop3r It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. You only need to understand that it needs to be a full answer to the question asked. That includes some code and a description of what was wrong. Also, copying somebody else's answer is also a no-go.

Comment: @Classicalclown Please try to be more careful about how you post code. I indented your code properly, but you will have to learn how to do it yourself like marking the code in question and hitting Ctrl+K. Also, you can edit your own answer. You don't have to delete an answer and post a new one.

Comment: Why was i down voted for answering my question on decreasing tripples then? Was it b/c i answered it as if i wasn't the ome who asked it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/36818054/3281844